# Divergence is negative while the field seems to be expanding geometrically

Tags: derivatives, vector-fields, divergence-operator

[image]

Hi, I was trying to solve this question. If we assume that the field is defined in space, the divergence becomes 0 which makes sense(even though the function is expanding) because the field is not defined at the origin. But if we assume that the field is defined in the $xy$ plane(which actually isn't what the question intended), the divergence becomes negative.($\dfrac{-1}{r^3}$)

I don't understand why this happens. The function seems to be expanding geometrically so the divergence should be positive.

---

This is how I computed: $\dfrac{-1}{r^3}$:

$v = \dfrac{1}{(x^2 + y^2)^{\dfrac{3}{2}}} \times (xi + yj)$

$=> \nabla . v = \dfrac{2r^3 - 3r^3}{r^6} = \dfrac{-1}{r^3}$

Comment: You should find the divergence is zero in 3D, except at the origin. Note that the vector in the numerator is unit, so it is not just the coordinate vector.

Comment: Here is someone who asked the same question on physics SE: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20604/divergence-of-frac-hatrr2

Comment: As I have written I solved it in 2D. In 3D I have no problem solving the problem.

Comment: @Hushus46 that question is in 3D. My problem is that if we assume the field is in the plane, the divergence becomes 0.

Comment: @Soroushkhoubyarian It should be 0. I believe your question and the one I linked are the same question 1.16 from Griffiths Intro to Electrodynamics

Comment: @Hushus46 No, I have no problem solving this question. My question is that if the field was defined in the plane, the divergence would be negative which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that $\nabla \cdot \left ( \frac{\mathbf{r}}{r^3} \right ) < 0$ if $\mathbf{r} \neq \mathbf{0}$ in 2D. But it is a positive delta function at the origin. Consequently the integral of it over a disk centered at the origin is still positive, in accordance with the outward character of the field. This negativity is saying that the flux through a circle decays as the radius of the circle grows. This can be viewed as a consequence of the fact that in 3D the surface area of the sphere is proportional to $r^2$ while in 2D it is proportional to $r$ (so the flux behaves like $1/r$ which decays). This fact also shows up in the difference between the fundamental solutions to the Laplace equation in 2D and 3D.